# ImportError when running Django on Apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, vagrant, mod-wsgi

I've followed the Django tutorial for setting up a project to run with mod_wsgi, but I'm stuck on an ImportError when trying to access my site. I'm running the Apache server through Vagrant.

This is the actual error from Apache logs:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=4268): Target WSGI script '/vagrant/myapp/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=4268): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/vagrant/myapp/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/vagrant/myapp/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py", 
     application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
     app_config.import_models(all_models)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 197, in import_models
     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
     __import__(name)
   File "/vagrant/myapp/myapp/myapp/comment/models.py", line 3, in <module>
     from myapp.post.models import Post
   File "/vagrant/myapp/myapp/myapp/post/models.py", line 4, in <module>
     from myapp.item.models import Item
   File "/vagrant/myapp/myapp/myapp/item/models.py", line 5, in <module>
     from myapp.third_party.otherapp.service import SomeService
   File "/vagrant/myapp/myapp/myapp/third_party/otherapp/service.py", line 1, in <module>
     from myapp.third_party.otherapp.api import SomeApi
ImportError: No module named api
```

This is my wsgi.py:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/vagrant/myapp/myapp/')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is my .conf file for the virtual host in sites-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 192.168.33.3
  ServerAlias vagrant.localhost
  DocumentRoot /vagrant

  WSGIScriptAlias / /vagrant/myapp/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py

  WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-path=/vagrant/myapp/myapp
  WSGIProcessGroup myapp

  <Directory /vagrant>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    <Files /vagrant/myapp/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It seems like my python path is incorrect somehow, but I've tried adding my app directory into wsgi.py to no avail. The import of the specified module works fine in the Django shell. Is there something else I'm missing to make this work?

**Edit**: This is the directory structure -

```
vagrant
-- Vagrantfile
-- myapp
----- myapp
-------- manage.py
-------- myapp
----------- urls.py
----------- settings.py
----------- wsgi.py
----------- post
----------- item
----------- third_party
----------- ...
```

Comment: How does your file structure look?

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` files in the package directories?

Comment: Yes, they all have an `__init__.py`

Comment: Is mod_wsgi running as different user? Does it have permissions on that file?

Comment: The user was the problem - I set WSGIDaemonProcess to run as the vagrant user and it works now! Thank you @DomenBlenkuš.